# Show that if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

I'm new to the page, I was hoping that you could help me solve this example so I can get carried away to do my practice exercises.It's an exercise in inequality, maybe it's not difficult, but as soon as I start the topic I have several doubts.

The exercise is: 
Show that if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $$0<x<1$$ and $$0<y<1,$$ then $$xy(1-x)(1-y)\le \frac{1}{16}$$

Thank you for your help to get a better score on my upcoming test.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and the specific places in which you're feeling doubtful?

Comment: Hint: this is an application of the ([tag:a.m.-g.m.-inequality]).

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I can upload photos to the platform?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are near zero, that inequality is clearly false.

Comment: It's easy to see the reverse is true $$xy(1-x)(1-y)\le \frac{1}{16}$$ with AM-GM.

Comment: $x=y=.1$ then $0.1^2*0.9^2 = .0081< \frac 1{16}$ so you have the equation backwards.  Let $x=\frac 12 \pm e$ and $1-x=1-(\frac 12 \pm e) = \frac 12 \mp e$ and $y= \frac 12 \pm d$ and $1-y=\frac 12 \mp d$ and assume $\frac 12 > e,d\ge 0$.  Then $xy(1-x)(1-y)=(\frac 12 + d)(\frac 12-d)(\frac 12 +e)(\frac 12-e)=(\frac 14 - e^2)(\frac 14 - d^2) = \frac 1{16} -\frac 14e^2 - \frac 14d^2 +\frac 16e^2d^2$.  Can you prove $ -\frac 14e^2 - \frac 14d^2 +\frac 16e^2d^2 \le 0$?

Comment: Find maximum value with two variables. Max value is the for point at center of square is $1/ 2^4$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Find maximum of the function $f(x)=x(1-x)$.

This requires no knowledge about AM-GM inequality, as in other solutions. Only basic knowledge about quadratic function is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By AM-GM Inequality,
$$x(1-x)y(1-y) \le \left(\frac{x+1-x+y+1-y}{4}\right)^{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality should be reversed.

I may show that $x(1-x) \leq 1/4$. By AM-GM, $x + (1-x) \geq 2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$, implying the above.

As $x,y$ are independent, the inequality follows.

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt:

$ g(x)=x(1-x)$ ; $f(y)=y(1-y)$.

Note : $x$ and $y$ are independent variables,

$x,y \in (0,1)$.

1) Consider $g'(x)= 1-2x=0$.

Maximum of $g(x)$ is  at $x=1/2$.

2)Likewise:

Maximum of $f(y)$ at $y=1/2$.

3)Maximum of $g(x)f(y)$ at $x=y=1/2$:

$\max (f(x)g(y)) =(1/2)^4= (1/16).$

4) Hence $g(x)f(y) \le 1/(16)$, $x,y \in (0,1)$.